# How to specify Tomcat logs as home for log4j log file

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

My WAR is using a log4j FileAppender configured via a `log4j.properties` file under the `classes/` directory inside the WAR.

I have configured my log4j appender as such:

```
# Set the root logger to DEBUG.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

# MonitorLog - used to log messages in the Monitor.log file.
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.File=MonitorLog.log
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Use the MonitorAppender to log all messages.
log4j.logger.*=DEBUG,MonitorAppender
```

With this configuration I am trying to achieve the following:

- All log messages DEBUG-level and higher get logged (so everything)
- I want the `MonitorLog.log` file to be located under Tomcat's `logs/` directory

Does this configuration achieve these items, and if not, what needs to change?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you know this WAR will only be deployed to a tomcat, you can take advantage of the system property `catalina.base`, which represents the root of your tomcat base folder (there is also a `cataline.home`, but they are often the same unless you have multiple tomcats running on the same machine and are sharing the server libs, but i digress).

So update as follows:

```
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.File=${catalina.base}/logs/MonitorLog.log
```

Comment: For those who run the application from Eclipse - the `${catalina.base}` variable will be replaced by `%WORKSPACE%\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1` where `%WORKSPACE%` is the actual workspace absolute path.